# Angular 8 :Get data from JSON server and Filter data in table using Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular7, angular8

I am working on an angular project and need help with how to filter data using checkboxes in a table.
I have a home component in which data is getting displayed from a json server in table format using a service.
I have another filter component where i have implemented filters.
If a user click on a filter , the data in the table should change based on the checkbox input.

### Home.component.ts file where table is loaded

```
       export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
      SearchValue: any;
      p:number = 1;
      constructor(public rs:RestService) {}
   
      @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
      @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
      dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
        ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.rs.getUsers().subscribe((Response) => {
         this.dataSource.data=Response;
         })
      }
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['empId','name', 'email', 'mobile', 'gender'];
}
```

### Checkbox example in filter.component.html

```
<div *ngFor = "let obj of filter">
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{obj.value}}" (change)=filterChange($event)> {{obj.key}}
  </div>
```

### Service.ts file

```
<pre><code>
export class RestService {
constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
url:string = "http://localhost:3000/Users";
getUsers() {
return this.http.get<Users[]>(this.url);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
filterChange(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: @wscourge If you think it is not enough feel free to edit my answer

Comment: Where should i use this filterChange function. As i have a filterComponent seperate , then table in a seperate component and it is getting data from a service.

Comment: I think I got you. In your filter.component.ts you can create @Output and emit the filterValue to the home.component.ts. Is that make sense?